# C++ linked list with classes

Tags: c++

So I have a problem with my head node changing when I add a new node to the list. I have to read in multiple lines from a file. Each line is going to be a function f(x) = ... and the nodes are singular expressions in the function so node 1 for example can be 25x^2 and node 2 could be 15x. So my Node class holds the coefficient so for node 1 it would be 25, and the exponent x goes to. Here's the pieces of code that are causing the problem I think.

```
Node* n = new Node();
List nodeList;
nodeList.setHead(NULL);

while(not at the end of line)
{
//This while loop just inputs from file, and stores values into Node class.
if(!nodeList.getHead()) //so this is first node being input.
{
    //i collect the values for coefficient and exponent here...
    n->setCoef(coef);
    n->setExp(exp);
    nodeList.insertNode(n);
}
else //so this is not the first node in the list.
{
    //i collect the values for coefficient and exponent again here...
    //After this code below, the head node changes to n's coef and exp.
    //I know this is because n is still pointing at the head node
    //but I keep getting runtime errors when trying to fix this.
    n->setCoef(coef);
    n->setExp(exp);
    nodeList.insertNode(n);
}
```

}

Here is my List::insertNode(Node* n) class:

```
void List::insertNode(Node* n){
//if theres no head node, just set it to the n node and continue.
if (!head)
    head = n;
else{
    Node* ptr = head; //used to traverse through list.
    bool likeTerms = false;
    while(ptr) //This while loop checks to make sure theres no like terms.
    {
        if (ptr->getExp() == n->getExp()){
            likeTerms = true;
            break;
        }
        ptr = ptr->getNext();
    }
    //If they aren't like terms, just add the node to the end.
    if (!likeTerms){
        ptr = head;
        while(ptr->getNext() != NULL)
        {
            ptr = ptr->getNext(); //traverses to the last node in list.
        }
        ptr->setNext(n); //Adds the new node to the spot after the last node
    }
    else if (likeTerms == true)//If the x exponents have like terms, 
                               //then just combine them.
        ptr->setCoef(ptr->getCoef()+n->getCoef());
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

The code to insert node for each line can also be simplified as following since the two statements of `if-else` condition are equivalent. The variable of `Node* n` need to be created in the `while-loop` or the `nodeList` would contain only one node with the last item of the function f(x).

```
while (not at the end of line)
{
    Node* n = new Node;
    n->setCoef(coef);
    n->setExp(exp);
    nodeList.insertNode(n);
}
```

The function `void List::insertNode(Node* n)` can also be simplified. The following is the simplified version.

```
void List::insertNode(Node* n) {
    Node* ptr  = header;
    Node* prev = NULL;
    bool  same_exp_occurred = false;
    while (ptr) {
        if (n->getExp() == ptr->getExp()) {
            ptr->setCoef(ptr->getCoef()+n->getCoef());
            same_exp_occurred = true;
            break;
        }
        prev = ptr;
        ptr  = ptr->getNext();
    }

    if (!same_exp_occurred && prev) {
        prev->setNext(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help in improving my code. I'll definitely look over it. I found the problem though. I worded the question poorly, but basically I was creating only one node and trying to add that same node in to the list every time but with different values. Instead of using Node* n, I just replaced the line, nodeList.insertNode(n);, with nodeList.insertNode( new Node(coef, exp, NULL));

Comment: Your welcome. I am too focus on the simplification of the code and just simply put the code `Node* n = new Node;` in the while loop without any explanation or comment. As a result, I do not answer your question directly.